# How to keep time zone in solr when importing from MySQL?

Tags: php, solr

I am running solr 7.7.x which imports data including dates from MySQL. In the DB the time is saved to the servers current time zone. After solr imports, it converts to UTC. This leads to a shift of 2h in my case when pulling the data:

MySQL:

```
"date_created":"2019-04-01 17:18:45"
```

MySQL import query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( c.date_created, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ' ) AS date_created FROM cls
```

solr:

```
"date_created":"2019-04-01T19:18:45Z",
```

PHP:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($item['date_created']));
```

I also tried:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$date = new DateTime($classified['date_created']);
$date->setTimezone($tz);
$ad['time_created'][$index] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Same result, the time is offset by 2 hours. If I change the DateTimeZone to US, it will offset bei 9h, which shows that at least it has some effect.

I temporarily fixed it by: `$ad['time_created'][$index] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($classified['date_created'])-7200);` which does not look like a good solution to me.

How can I keep the time from MySQL and what is the recommened approach to deal with timezones in solr?

Comment: Solr does not have a concept of timezones, except for the `TZ` parameter when querying. Everything internally will be in UTC. However, if MySQL were converting from a timezone (Europe/Berlin) when exporting, shouldn't the correct value be `15:18:45` since Europe/Berlin is `+0200` at the moment?

Comment: Interesting. I have added the MySQL import query to the question. Might this be the reason? Berlin ist +2 UTC

Comment: You can [use the logtransformer if you're using DIH to import content](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#LogTransformer) - that'll allow you to log the actual value returned from your query and help determine what happens with the value. Initial guess: the Java ODBC thinks the returned date from MySQL is in UTC, but the local server is set to +02:00, so it adds two hours to it. There is [some timezone support in the DIH by itself](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will solve your problem or not but you can sync Solr's timezone with MySQL timezone by assigning a timezone to solr, by default solr work on UTC timezone.

If Solr is on Windows machine, assign timezone as below in solr-x.x.x\bin\solr.in.cmd

```
set SOLR_TIMEZONE=<yourTimezone>
```

and if Solr is on linux, in solr-x.x.x\bin\solr.in.sh

```
SOLR_TIMEZONE="<yourTimezone>"
```